# Have I destroyed data on drive?

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, dd

I stupidly ran the following command on an external ext4 USB disk, typing `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sda` which was the new disk I was setting up:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=100
```

These were the lines I used to initially set up that drive, I was just going to repeat them:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=100  
parted -a optimal /dev/sdb mklabel gpt  
parted -a optimal /dev/sdb mkpart -- primary ext4 1 -1  
mkfs.ext4 -L BIGDRIVE /dev/sdb1
```

Can I retrieve the boot sector and get the drive operational again?

Comment: Most data is still there (well, all but 50kb). All is not lost. I'm not an expert here, so I'll just wait for somebody else to write out how exactly to proceed... but essentially, you probably have to rebuild the partition table and (I'm not sure how much is destroyed) recover the root inode of the first partition - it depends on how or if even this drive was partitioned and what the offsets are.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've got testdisk running on Yosemite and it has found the partition data- it says the structure is OK. Will a simple 'write' bring the partition back?

Comment: It really all depends on what was there before: gpt, mbr? Given that the partitions are nowadays aligned to 1MB, only the partition table was destroyed (not sure how much). I would do this: `dd` the first megabyte into some backup file just to be sure. The first 50kb are zeroes anyway, but if anything goes wrong, you'll have the dump to put back. Then rewrite the partition table and try to mount all partitions (read-only!). If it works, that's it.

Comment: Disk was gpt. After testdisk did its recovery it seems OK. Anyone who is an expert with testdisk could tell me if I've fully repaired the damage (if any). All I did was get it to recognise the partition table and then used the 'write' option. I have no idea if this was the right thing, but the disk now mounts under OpenElec (the distro I'm using).

Comment: If all partitions can be mounted, this is it. The only real job of the partition table is to find the correct ranges where partitions are located. Everything else is just sugar and can be changed later if you notice any difference (partition types, bootable flags and so on). You can run `fsck` on all partitions if there is any extra damage, but it should be fine. You didn't damage the data part of the disk.

Comment: I think with only 50kB wipe you should be able to recover most if not all of your files after restoring the partition table. **Do not run `mkfs`**! That would destroy any hope of recovery.

Comment: Your disk should be fine now—you could run `e2fsck -f` (with it unmounted, of course) to be sure. And add an answer to your own question, saying how to use `testdisk` to fix.